# Вывод даты/времени TIMESTAMP из MySQL

Tags: java, jsp, дата, mysql

Здравствуйте! Как возможно вывести из mysql в jsp-страницу отформатированную дату вида "hh:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy"? Сейчас выводит в формате "2012-09-25 12:31:13.0", в классе есть getters/setters, но возвращаемое значение не String, а Date. Пытался отформатировать, но тогда возвращается строка.

Comment: А что `Date` полученный от мускула отформатировать через `SimpleDateFormat` никак?

Comment: не получается, выдает ошибку, указал ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SimpleDateFormatExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date now = new Date();
        String datetimeStr = now.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                   "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        try {
            Date parseDate = format.parse(datetimeStr);
            System.out.println(parseDate.toString());
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо, но во-первых не тот формат, мне нужен <code>"hh:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy"</code>, выдает ошибку unparseable data

Comment: Я читаю из базы, а не создаю новую дату из Java.

Comment: В запросе можно сделать DATE_FORMAT(date, "Y:m:d H:i:s") ну под себя конечно формат поправите.

Comment: спасибо, но мне надо в Java отформатировать а не в Mysql

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: если вы из базы читаете, значит вам уже пришел объект типа Date, ну а формат подстройте под себя как захотите