# Неправильные даты

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть приложение написанное через Spring MVC,Spring JDBC.Необходимо добавлять дату в БД(MYSQL).

Класс

```
public class Request {
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dueDate;
```

jsp

```
<form:form action="create" commandName="request" method="post">
    <form:input type="date" path="dueDate"/>
    <input type="submit" value="create">
</form:form>
```

соед с бд

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Проблема в том,что дата введенная в форму,отличается на 1 день, от той которая сохраняется в бд. 
То есть если в форму вводится 2012-12-12 , в бд сохранено 2012-12-11.
Как это можно решить.Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод даты/времени TIMESTAMP из MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148456/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-timestamp-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql)

Comment: @Санаев Не похоже как по мне. Скорее всего UTC сдвиг часовых поясов, но я не знаток java.

Comment: @AK смысл один и тот же

Comment: Упс точно вопрос не прочитал полностью

Comment: В бд по всей видимости с 0 дня начинается отчёт , поэтому при считывании с бд 1 прибавлять придётся.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать LocalDate

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо.
Решено изменением serverTimeZone с UTC на Europe